# jQuery character count, separating into two text boxes on limit

Tags: jquery, character-limit

I am working on a page that accepts entry into a single textarea, then splits the contained text across two output textareas in realtime should it reach a certain character limit (the first with 0 - x characters, the second with x - end). I have the copying process working, but am at a loss on how to approach the division and have the first textbox stop accepting input while continuing real-time entry on the second one.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the cursor between textboxes by using.

```
$('newTextBox').focus();
```

For the charater limit, use this.

```
<textarea maxlength="50">

</textarea>
```

Note that it doesn't work on Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to call `.focus()` on the second box to force the cursor into it